# Lock post editing to one user at a time - wp_check_post_lock

Tags: posts, front-end

I am creating a website where user have to be logged in to give a price bid on a product. Only one bid can be given on the product.  Therefore, I only want one user at a time to be able to give a bid.  Is it possible to lock post editing to one user from the frontend?  So if 2 or more user enters a post simultaneously, could a message tell the other user that someone else is giving a bid?

I had a quick look at this function from post.php wp_check_post_lock, but if I call it from my theme, it is unrecognized.

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine the following situation: One user leaves the browser window.

```
What happens? No other user can place a bid.
```

If you're using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) to fire up the bid, then you can add the `wp_check_post_lock()` function in there. And also remove the lock. So the post is only locked as long as someone is *actually placing/sending* the bid. As this will only last for some ms, you have successfully worked around the post lock problem.

**Edit**

There's a new "post lock" feature for post types coming. This will be in 3.6 or 3.7. So far, no further details are known.